# Webpage is not fully loaded by a browser

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, browser

Currently I'm trying to do the layout for my shopping website. I've come across weird problem I do not understand whether it's my fault or a browser (but I'm more likely to think that I've done something wrong.). My page is not loading fully, it looks like browser loads a part of it and then stops. However if I put some even random words or letters below the code, for each letter I put a one character of expected content shows up. And there is nothing apart from some php (that should now affect html view I guess), and bootstrap used apart from html.

And since the html I wrote is rather long I'll post those parts in a github gists to make this post more readable.

Here's the code:
https://gist.github.com/kbialy92/73301401014624de3f73

So is it a problem that is somehow connected to the browser, memory usage or just the code written incorrectly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how to ask questions. In this case include some code and make a jsfiddle.net with rendered html. If there are console errors include them too. Alternatively ask on codereview.

Comment: You have two `<html>` tags. In `index.php` and `head.php`. Lose one.

Comment: @mplungjan If there are errors it's off topic for Code Review and better kept here instead.

Comment: @mplungjan I've done what you asked for and it doesn't show any errors and display page pretty much the way it is supposed to. 
Here is the link to jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8geaspq2/

Comment: so served from PHP it does not load, but if you view-source and paste into jsfiddle it works?

Comment: Exactly. It doen't work properly on a localhost but when I pasted it to jsfiddle it seems to be just fine.

Comment: JSFiddle doesn't do PHP, so it ignores all the PHP stuff and shows only the content it can handle. And it uses standards mode rather than quirks mode which your PHP document triggers. Anyhow, I can't duplicate the behaviour you're reporting; everything shows up. Could there be some overflow:hidden style somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Your php is dieing. Try using

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

At the top of your php code. A half printed page means that you are printing some html then when you get to the error, the output stream is cut short.

If you can't find the problem, upload the php code here for review.